# Determining which Mercurial version which created a repository

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, mercurial

I have a rather large Mercurial web server (ie. running under `hgweb.wsgi`) that's outgrown the distribution it was built-on... which basically means that I've already started doing upgrades of Python, Apache, OpenSSL, mod-wsgi, and Mercurial (among other things), rather than being more-responsible and upgrading the underlying O/S (don't hate on me).

The question here, is... what is the best way to determine which version of `hg` actually *created* any given repository. Ideally, I'm looking to get rid of the older database versions and help make sure those repos basically "keep up" with current versions of Mercurial.

I understand the general `.hg/requires` file, which can give you "compatibility requirements," but that does completely answer the question of "how old was the version of Mercurial that created this repo?"

That said, there's probably *some* place that lists the "new" requirements for any particular version, so you can artificially construct a version matrix? Unfortunately, I was unlucky on the mercurial-scm.org site in finding anything definitive.